# Is there any regular expression in pandas where we can define, first and last characters, and whatever come in between

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

If i have column names like this in df:

```
    Q24r639606c1: Good Quality      Q24r64500c1: Bad       Q25r64500c1: Amazing          Q24r64500c2: Worst         Q24r5200c1: Nice   
               A                            A                     B                              B                 

               D                            F                     C                              G                 K
```

I want to filter columns which start with "Q24 and, has "c1" before colon ":"

I am trying this but here i can pass only one string

```
Selected_Columns = df.filter(regex = 'Q24r')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter using startswith Q24 (`^Q24`). Then allow for anything `(.*)` until you locate exactly `'c1:'`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Q24r639606c1: Good Quality', 'Q24r64500c1: Bad',
                           'Q25r64500c1: Amazing', 'Q24r64500c2: Worst', 'Q24r5200c1: Nice'])

df.filter(regex='^Q24.*c1:').columns
['Q24r639606c1: Good Quality', 'Q24r64500c1: Bad', 'Q24r5200c1: Nice'],
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i wanted :)